# How to float text within a block like it was inline?

Tags: javascript, css

Given an image and a div which is is a column that is inside another div which is the content, how to make the column which has a fixed width and is a display block float its text aside the image?

```
 <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
<div id="content">
<div class="column">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est. 
</div>    
</div>
```

This is the code reference http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rawjLQ

The closest thing I can think of is to place an empty div into the column, grab the width of the image with js and set it to the empty div inside the column and float like the two elements where inside the same container...

Is there a jquery library to do such a thing?

Comment: `display: inline-block`?

Comment: Your image is larger than the text column. If you set it's size to something smaller than the width of the column it will float as intended.

Comment: display inline-block, will float on the right but not on the bottom. The image width does not matter in this case

Comment: who downvoted and why? now i am banned...great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the placeholder seems the easiest solution...

```
    img{
  float: left;
}
#content{
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
}
.column{
  width: 800px;
}
#placeholder{
  width: 550px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEwLOd